# How to display "0" in form if $_POST['a'] is a letter?

Tags: php, post, if-statement

So this is my code, as of now, the form takes all kinds of input (string and integer).
How can I specify for example: if `$_POST['a']` is a letter, set `$_SESSION['a']` to 0 ?

As of now, If I pass a letter to the form, the letter will still get passed to `$_SESSION` and get recorded when I click "update". I need it to ignore and set the letter to 0 in the form.

index.php is this same file

Thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset($_POST["a"]) && isset($_POST["b"]) && isset($_POST["c"]) ) {
    $_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['a'];
    $_SESSION['b'] = $_POST['b'];
    $_SESSION['c'] = $_POST['c'];
    header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
    return;
}
?>

// ( some code... )

$a = isset($_SESSION['a']) ? $_SESSION['a'] : '0';
$b = isset($_SESSION['b']) ? $_SESSION['b'] : '0';
$c = isset($_SESSION['c']) ? $_SESSION['c'] : '0';   

// ( some code...)

<form method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="a" size="3" value="<?php echo(htmlentities($a)); ?>"> A </p>
    <p><input type="text" name="b" size="3" value="<?php echo(htmlentities($b)); ?>"> B </p>
    <p><input type="text" name="c" size="3" value="<?php echo(htmlentities($c)); ?>"> C </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I generally use [ctype_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php) functions to determine character types in strings with PHP. In this case, [ctype_alpha](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php).

```
if (ctype_alpha($_POST['a'])) { 
    $_SESSION['a'] = 0;
}
```